# AEM Mocks missing artifact for latest version

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, sling

I have added the latest version of [AEM Mocks](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.wcm/io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.junit5) (2.7.2) as a Maven dependency in my AEM project. When I try to build my project, I get an error saying that this artifact cannot be found: `com.day.commons:day-commons-gfx:jar:2.1.28`. So I looked online, [found it](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.day.commons/day-commons-gfx/2.1.28) and added it as a dependency. But now I get the same error when trying to build. Does this artifact still exist? When trying various recent versions of AEM Mocks, I found that they all depend on this missing artifact.

For now, I downgraded to version 2.3.0, which works fine without that artifact but I would like to use the most recent version if possible.

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This artifact is defined as a workaround, it is explained here in comment:
https://github.com/wcm-io/wcm-io-testing/blob/develop/aem-mock/core/pom.xml#L254:

> Workaround for AEM 6.5: The new uber-jar does no longer contain the package com.day.imageio.plugins

It works without any issues for me, so I would check if you have correctly configured Maven repositories. To do it, in your Maven project root type:

`mvn help:evaluate`

and then:

`${project.repositories}`

It should list your project effective repositories. Ensure that there is Central Repository (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) listed. If it is there, then maybe your corporate network cuts requests to external repositories or it was temporarily down.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment! 

Running the first command lists various jars and bundles. Running the second command ${project.repositories}, gives this error (I use the zsh shell): zsh: bad substitution

I'm not sure what exactly I'm supposed to see when running the first command (or the second). When you say "Ensure that there is Central Repository (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) listed", isn't that supposed to come with the Maven Super POM by default?

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: Yes, it should be in super POM by default, but it's better to ensure. ${project.repositories} is not a command, but value to print during the first command execution. mvn help:evaluate should wait for input from you and it should be "${project.repositories}".

Comment: mvn help:evaluate starts printing immediately without me providing any input. It prints the Reactor Build Order: POM, bundles and jars in the project. I don't see anything like the Central Repository (though it may be there, I don't know). Is there an easy way to get this dependency? Can I get day-commons-gfx from some other place? Thanks!