# AEM Mocks: Cannot Inject Config

Tags: unit-testing, aem, sling

I am using [AEM Mocks](https://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/) to test a custom servlet that uses a configuration, as such:

```java
@Activate
void activate(final Config config) { ... }
```

I am following the approach described [here](https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2019/01/09/writing-unit-tests-for-aem-using-slingmocks/) and [here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.junit.OsgiContext/registerInjectActivateService) to register and inject the service together with a HashMap, as such:

```java
private static Map<String, Object> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();

...

myHashMap.put("a", "b");
myHashMap.put("c", "d");

...

servlet = context.registerInjectActivateService(new MyServlet(), myHashMap);
```

However, this approach doesn't work. The config object passed above, inside the `activate` function, is corrupted. For every key-value pair above, it sets `null` as the value. So instead of:

```java
a -> b
c -> d
```

It sets:

```java
a -> null
c -> null
```

Inside the HashMap. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

P.S. I should add that I am using version 2.3.0 of AEM Mocks since the recent versions cause an issue with an older artifact. For more info on that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417178/aem-mocks-missing-artifact-for-latest-version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it, and it works with version 2.3.0 too. Could you check the following example? After that, it is probably a maven issue. Then we would need more information.

Here is my test servlet:

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class,
        property = {
                SLING_SERVLET_PATHS + "=/bin/servlet/test",
                SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=GET",
                SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=text"
        })
@Designate(ocd = TestServlet.Config.class)
public class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @ObjectClassDefinition
    public @interface Config {

        @AttributeDefinition(
                name = "Name",
                description = "Name used in the hello world text"
        )
        String name() default "Alex";

        @AttributeDefinition(
                name = "Greeting",
                description = "Greeting - Morning, to demonstrate the dot-replacement"
        )
        String greeting_morning() default "Good Morning";
    }

    private Config config;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(@Nonnull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.getWriter().println(this.getGreeting());
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return config.greeting_morning() + ", " + config.name();
    }

    @Activate
    void activate(final Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

Here is a JUnit 4 test:

```
public class TestServletTest {

    @Rule
    public final AemContext context = new AemContext();

    @Test
    public void testWithoutConfig() {
        final TestServlet testServlet = context.registerInjectActivateService(new TestServlet());
        assertEquals("Good Morning, Alex", testServlet.getGreeting());
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithConfig() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("name", "Berndt");
        properties.put("greeting.morning", "Keep sleeping");
        final TestServlet testServlet = context.registerInjectActivateService(new TestServlet(), properties);

        assertEquals("Keep sleeping, Berndt", testServlet.getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot reproduce your result on my end so it may indeed be a maven issue. I will look into it further - its helpful to know that the default way of doing things does indeed work and in version 2.3.0.

Comment: Please add your effective pom.xml to the question. Maybe we can look into it (add `help:effective-pom` to your maven command line)

Comment: I can't add it since its proprietary code, but the tip about private is interesting. I may have set AemContext or the config to private. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: No. I meant private stuff like server-names, phone numbers or passwords in your pom.xml.